# How do you add a breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have written my first Hello World Objective C program.
How do I add a breakpoint and inspect a variable?
I can see a Breakpoints button but can't insert one.

Comment: **Shortcut**: Insert cursor on the line you want, then hit "Command + \".

Comment: Or just click in the left edge window border next to the required line.

Comment: As I just learned from the docs I linked, the edge is called *Gutter*

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut that works on a non-english keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is useful for you: [Xcode Debugging Guide](https://developer.apple.com/support/debugging/)
[image]

Comment: enabling line numbers shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 10):

Command + \ to add breakpoint at current line

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to right click or any such thing. To enable the breakpoints in your code all you have to do is click on a particular line number. You'll get a breakpoint symbol in your code there.

You can add multiple breakpoints to your code. The breakpoints button on top is used to put all your breakpoints ON (during debugging) or OFF (when necessary)

I'll be addressing a section on breakpoints in my blog ( http://techtalktone.wordpress.com ) soon.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 2):

use menu entry **Product**->**Debug**->**Add Breakpoint at Current line**

that menu also shows the shortcuts for similar actions