# how to pass an image from collection view to detail view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Retrieving data from Remote XML, I can show up the images in collection view. From this collection view I'm trying to display a detailed view controller, where if an image is clicked in collection view controller it should display the image in detailed view. I got stuck here where I can't show the detail view controller. Where am I going wrong? Kindly guide me.

Below is my Collection view Controller,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   xmlParser = [[MyXMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:@"http://MyXml.com/sample.xml"];
   myarray = xmlParser.arrayofimages;
  }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
  {
    return 1;
  }

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return [myarray count];
  }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
     MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     if (!myCell) {
         myCell = [[MyCollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,myCell.frame.size.width , myCell.frame.size.height)];
     }
    [myCell.tweetImageView setImage:[myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return myCell;
  }

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    detailVC.img= [myarray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

**DetailView Controller**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
  {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.imageView.image = self.img;
  }
```

Comment: please verify the nib name given at 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in Collection View Controller,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

You had missed this line.

Comment: i had added it no change. am not getting the detail view controller

Answer (score 1):

You are not presenting your detailview controller. You just allocating it.

Instead of:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    detailVC.img= [myarray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
  }
```

Check:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    detailVC.img= [myarray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
   [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Comment: I added as your suggestion but it remains same no change. i cant move to detail view controller

Comment: put a breakpoint on the didselect method and viewdidload of detailview and tell me it's hitting or not

Comment: Am new to iPhone development sorry, can you tell me how to do that

Comment: @Sabarish: please check this link for adding the breakpoint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931959/how-do-you-add-a-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: ya i did as you said added break points and viewed in navigator. it shows nothing

Comment: @Sabarish: after putting breakpoint, run the code again. On pressing a cell, is the break point on the didselect method is triggered ?

Comment: Am not sure it triggered or not but my output window shows  `XMLParsing[4474:c07] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyCollectionViewController: 0x755d360>`

Comment: @Sabarish: sorry dude, I can't help you without any information about code or breakpoint triggering or method flow

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Assign image after presenting the view

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
       [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    detailVC.img= [myarray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

Comment: It remains same, no change in it

Comment: Is your problem with loading image or push to detail view?

Comment: i can load the image in collection view but when i click the image for detail view i cant push it from collection view controller to detail view controller

Comment: Try [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES]; instead of [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil]; Debug and conform that this function is get called