# How to get actual error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

My iOS App is being crashed in Xcode simulator with EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue. How to get the actual error as there is nothing in Logs and also catch block is not catching the error.

I am assigning value to the following property of class

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDecimalNumber *amount;
```

Assigning the value in following code in another file.

```
cd.amount   = chargeAmount;
```

amount is NSDecimalNumber. I am using another property of type NSString in the same way but there is no issue in that. I am not sure why app crashes for amount.

Please suggest, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Set up an [exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931959/how-do-you-add-a-breakpoint-in-xcode).

Comment: There is no "actual error" for bad access. You are accessing a part of a memory you are not supposed to. If your decimal number is an issue then it is most likely not a decimal number. The first thing I would do is override the setter and getter for it and put breakpoints in it. Then check if at some point this value is corrupted like trying to print amount.integerValue and see if it crashes it.

Comment: @the4kman thank you for your reply. I tried exception breakpoint but still there is nothing.