# THREAD 1: signal SIGBART, when implementing camera function

Tags: ios, swift, camera, sigabrt, ios-camera

I'm having some trouble with implementing a camera function. I get signal SIGBART error in my @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate class, and I can't figure out why. I've tried searching in here, but without luck. Hopefully one of you can help!

```
@IBAction func cameraButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
    }
```

Comment: Set up an [exception breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931959/how-do-you-add-a-breakpoint-in-xcode).

Comment: Okay, thanks! Where do I ad the break point? I tried to put in several places, where I thought it made sense, but then I just got another error: Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.4.
Sorry, I'm just very new to this.

Comment: Try a general exception breakpoint without a place. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode) might help.

Comment: Damn, that did not help either, now it says Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1... I'll keep on looking on the Inter Web. Thanks for your help, you're a legend.