# Nil Error for UIWebView ONLY when loadRequest outside viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I'm receiving the following error

> "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

when I try to load a PDF file inside a web view that is presented via a container view.

I have the UIWebView properly linked up in IB and run the following code on the parent VC to tell the container view with the WebView to load the PDF file.

```
func loadThePDF () {
 if let pdf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Clothing", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
            let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf)
            catalogWebView.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
 }
}
```

The weird thing here, is that if I put the PDF load code into the ViewDidLoad, it works fine.

However trying to tell it to load the PDF outside of that causes this error, which can only be resolved by placing a ? on the catalogWebView? but then the PDF just doesn't load...

Comment: When you call `loadThePDF`, does the catalogWebView already defined? If you call it before `viewDidLoad`, chances are it isn't. But you can load it after by calling `loadThePDF` from `viewDidLoad` for instance

Comment: No it's called after view did load. As it's in a container view, the viewDidLoad is called when the parent view loads. And then the loadThePdf is called when I tap a button on the parent view.

Comment: Did you check if catalogWebView is properly set? Maybe double check the IBOutlet link, I've just managed to make it work.

Comment: What do you mean properly set? As far as the IB outlets, I've triple checked that. And again, that wouldn't work on the viewDidLoad if that was wrong.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint next to `catalogWebView` and once running, check what's in it before it crash? If it returns `nil` it means you're trying to load it before the view is set. If it's currently working in `viewDidLoad`, it looks like more like an issue of your usage vs the viewController life cycle. If still not working can you share the parentVC code?

Comment: Hi Ben, first of all thank you for your continued help with this. Second, I don't have much experience with breakpoints or knowing what to look for. If you could tell me more precisely what I need to do.

Although, from what you're saying I don't see how I can be trying to load before the view is set, because this works fine in the viewDidLoad, and then with this after the view has loaded I try to load the PDF and it doesn't work.

Comment: Any update @Ben ?

Comment: If you code is working in `viewDidLoad` or if you call `loadThePDF` from `viewDidLoad`, then that means your code seems working but you have a life cycle issue from your parentViewController. I can't help much more without the code as I described earlier. 
Regarding adding breakpoint, a simple search on Google and you can find many useful resources - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931959/how-do-you-add-a-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: But the load PDF is not in the viewdidload it’s in a manual call from a button. It’s most definitely after the view did load

Comment: As discussed earlier,I can create a UIViewController and load a pdf from a button without any issue, I don't think I can't help you much without seeing the rest of your code. Hope you find the issue otherwise

Comment: Well could you perhaps share your code, perhaps there's a step I'm taking wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by changing the way I link to the Child/Container view controller. For some reason this has solved the problem by using this:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pdfView" {
            pdfVC = segue.destination as? PDFViewController
        }
    }
```

Not entirely sure why, but I'm guessing it's something to do with how the ViewController links up when I tell it to load a new PDF in the web view on the container view.